# foreach argument to get specific file types getting too many returns

Tags: plugin-development, functions, php

So I am trying to display just the notes and the audio which are showing up with "AUDIO" and "TRANSCRIPT" as the output with a link to download them.

The issue I am having is that this also out put the featured image and the names of the uploaded PDF and MP3 show like this:

newyear2 (name of the featured image)
honest-wage (name of the audio file)
16-10-30_mh_the-day-after-the-election (name of PDF)
AUDIO (the files I want to show)
TRANSCRIPT (the file I want to show)

Here is the PHP code:

```
function wpfc_sermon_attachments() {
global $post;
$args        = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
$html        = '';
$html .= '<div id="wpfc-attachments" class="cf">';
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $html .= '<br/><a target="_blank" href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '">';
        $html .= $attachment->post_title;
    }
}
if ( get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_audio' ) ) {
    $html .= '<a href="' . get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_audio' ) . '" class="sermon-attachments"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __( 'AUDIO', 'sermon-manager' ) . '</a>';
}
if ( get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_notes' ) ) {
    $html .= '<a href="' . get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_notes' ) . '" class="sermon-attachments"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __( 'TRANSCRIPT', 'sermon-manager' ) . '</a>';
}
if ( get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_bulletin' ) ) {
    $html .= '<a href="' . get_wpfc_sermon_meta( 'sermon_bulletin' ) . '" class="sermon-attachments"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' . __( 'Bulletin', 'sermon-manager' ) . '</a>';
}
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</p>';
$html .= '</div>';

return $html;
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `'post_mime_type' => '...'` to your `$args`, as in:

```
$mime_types = array ('audio', 'application') ;
$args = array (
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type'    => $mime_types,
    ) ;
$query = new WP_Query ($args) ;
```

See [Mime-Type Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#mime-type-parameters) for more info.

It's not documented very well but the mime-types you set can be "partial", i.e., `audio` will match *all* audio formats, whereas `audio/mp3` will only match MP3, etc.

I'm not sure what mime-type your "TRANSCRIPT" has, but I'm sure you do.

Comment: To make it beneficial for others, the mime types I wanted were MP3 and PDF. Here is the result:

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpfc_sermon_attachments() {
global $post;
$args        = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio/mp3', 'application/pdf',
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);
```